# Create dataframe conditionally to other dataframe elements

Tags: python, pandas

Happy 2020! I would like to create a dataframe based on two others. I have the below two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['03.05.1982','04.05.1982','05.05.1982','06.05.1982','07.05.1982','10.05.1982','11.05.1982'],'A': [63.63,64.08,64.19,65.11,65.36,65.25,65.36], 'B': [63.83, 64.10, 64.19, 65.08, 65.33, 65.28, 65.36], 'C':[63.99, 64.22, 64.30, 65.16, 65.41, 65.36, 65.44]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','C'],'Notice': ['05.05.1982','07.05.1982','12.05.1982']})
```

The idea is to create df3 such that this dataframe takes the value of A until A's notice date (found in df2) is reached, then df3 switches to the values of B until B's notice date is reached and so on. When we are during notice date, it should take the mean between the current column and the next one.

In the above example, df3 should be as follows (with formulas to illustrate):

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'date':['03.05.1982','04.05.1982','05.05.1982','06.05.1982','07.05.1982','10.05.1982','11.05.1982'], 'Result':[63.63,64.08,(64.19+64.19)/2,65.08,(65.33+65.41)/2,65.36,65.44]})
```

My idea was to first create a temporary dataframe with same dimensions as df1 and to fill it with 1's when the index date is prior to notice and 0's after. Doing a rolling mean with window 1 would give for each column a series of 1 until I reach 0.5 (signalling a switch). 
**Not sure if there is a better way to get df3?**

I tried the following:

```
def fill_rule(df_p,df_t):
     return np.where(df_p.index > df_t[df_t.Name==df_p.name]['Notice'][0], 0, 1)

df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
df2['notice'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['notice'])
df1.set_index("date", inplace = True)

temp = df1.apply(lambda x: fill_rule(x, df2), axis = 0)
```

And I got the following error: `KeyError: (0, 'occurred at index B')`

Comment: your df2 doesn't have date?

Comment: it is "notice" sorry, not date, it is modified now

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `between` method to select the specific date ranges in both dataframes and then use `iloc` to substitute the specific values

```
#Initializing the output
df3 = df1.copy()
df3.drop(['B','C'], axis = 1, inplace = True)
df3.columns = ['date','Result']
df3['Result'] = 0.0
df3['count'] = 0


#Modifying df2 to add a dummy sample at the beginning
temp = df2.copy()
temp = temp.iloc[0]
temp = pd.DataFrame(temp).T
temp.Name ='Z'
temp.Notice = pd.to_datetime("05-05-1980")
df2 = pd.concat([temp,df2])


for i in range(len(df2)-1):
    startDate = df2.iloc[i]['Notice']
    endDate = df2.iloc[i+1]['Notice']

    name = df2.iloc[i+1]['Name']


    indices = [df1.date.between(startDate, endDate, inclusive=True)][0]


    df3.loc[indices,'Result'] += df1[indices][name]
    df3.loc[indices,'count'] += 1


df3.Result = df3.apply(lambda x : x.Result/x['count'], axis = 1)
```

Comment: hi Roshan - thanks a lot! It looks like it is working, I didnt know between. However, I have the same comment as above (Akhilesh's answer): if I am not mistaken, it does not take the mean (resp. between A and B values on 05.05.82 and then between B and C on 07.05.82) when we are at a notice date ?

Comment: Didnt realise you needed the mean of those days. That can be achieved by making a modification. I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
df1['t'] = df1['date'].map(df2.set_index(["Notice"])['Name'])
df1['t'] =df1['t'].fillna(method='bfill').fillna("C")

df3 = pd.DataFrame()
df3['Result'] = df1.apply(lambda row: row[row['t']],axis =1)
df3['date'] = df1['date']
```

Comment: This is brilliant..! Thank you - One thing, if I am not mistaken, it does not take the mean (resp. between A and B values on 05.05.82 and then between B and C on 07.05.82) when we are at a notice date